# Error: 'return' outside of function

Tags: python, python-2.7

Error: 'return' outside of function

Why??

```
 def get_all_students(self):
    database = open(self.database_path, 'r')
    list_of_students = list()
    for idx, l in enumerate(database.readlines()):
        params = list()
        params.append(idx)
        params += l.split(self.data_delimiter)
        student = Student(*self.item_un_escape(params))
        list_of_students.append(student)
    return list_of_students
```

Edit: I'll post the rest of the class, I'm pretty sure it's correctly indented though. Can't seem to find the error, I can bet it's probably something silly. Apologies, first time coding in python but this error has been annoying me for like an hour or so! haha

Edit2: It's throwing an error on params.append(idx) saying unexpected indentation?

```
from student import Student

database_path = 'C:/Users/Alan/Desktop/flask/flask/app/database'


class Database(object):
    data_delimiter = ','

    @staticmethod
    def escape_new_lines(value):
        if type(value) == str:
            value = value.replace('\n', '@n-nl@')
            value = value.replace('\r', '@r-nl@')
        return value

    @staticmethod
    def un_escape_new_lines(value):
        if type(value) == str:
            value = value.replace('@n-nl@', '\n')
            value = value.replace('@r-nl@', '\r')
        return value

    def __init__(self, database_path=database_path):
        self.database_path = database_path

    def get_all_students(self):
        database = open(self.database_path, 'r')
        list_of_students = list()
        for idx, l in enumerate(database.readlines()):
            params = list()
            params.append(idx)
            params += l.split(self.data_delimiter)
            student = Student(*self.item_un_escape(params))
            list_of_students.append(student)
        return list_of_students
```

Comment: You have probably got a mixture of tabs and spaces indenting your code.

Comment: That was the problem. Aha. Rookie mistake! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The code you have posted is fine. Your likely error is from missing an indent before a return statement. **EDIT:** As @Anonymous has noted in the comments, another possibility as that you're mixing tab indents with space indents. Check your indentations.